# "Precompile" function in python, compile-time computations

Tags: python, compile-time, compile-time-constant

If we write a function in python, whose execution depends on external variables that are already known, python will still check this every time

I mean

```
def fun():
    return 1 if False else 5
```

This "False" will be rechecked each time this function is called

This can be simply checked in a simple way:

```
def pp(t, s):
    print(s)
    return t

def returner(t):
    return t if pp(True, "YAY") else 0

list(map(returner,[1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Will print "YAY" 5 times

Is there a way to "precompile" a function so that such conditions are not checked every time it is called, but only when it is compiled

That is, a way to tell the compiler, "This expression is already known at compile time, figure it out and substitute it.

**Added in response to a post by @Chepner:**

You're right, but there is a third party: speed of execution.

In your example:

```
X = 5

def fun():
    return __precompute__(X * 5)

X = 7
```

I could really just write `return 25`, but what if the function is defined inside another function and its definition depends on the parameters passed to the function in which this definition takes place? I can't handwrite the return value right away, because I don't know the parameters passed in, but the defining function does.

In this case, it is assumed that the compile-time parameter is the parameter passed to the parent function, and it will never change again.

Example

```
def parent(parent_1, parent_2, parent_3, parent_4, long_array):
    def child(x):
        s = 0
        if parent_1:
            s += x**2
        if parent_2:
            s += x**x
        if parent_3:
            s += 2*x
        if parent_4:
            s += 74
        return s

    return sum(list(map(child, long_array)))
```

In this case, these parameters will not change, and each check will take a long time, when they can not be done at all

In "fast languages", such as C++, in this case, the child function absolutely cannot be optimized during program execution. But we deal with Python, where a program can change itself at runtime, so optimization and compilation of such a child function can theoretically happen at runtime.

My question is, are there technical means for such optimization and compilation of a function at runtime?

Comment: CPython has a peephole optimizer that will simplify some constant expressions at compile time. I somewhat surprised it doesn't simply this to `5`.

Comment: (It *does* simplify @pinegulf's suggest. You can use the `dis` module to see the byte code generated for each.) (He deleted his comment; `def fun(): if False: return 1 else: return 5` compiles to the same byte code as `def fun(): return 5`.)

Comment: Python itself is silent on the question of such optimizations, leaving them to individual implementations to provide as deemed appropriate or worthwhile.

Comment: @chepner but what with function `returner` and `pp`, it can be also optimized (if we delete `print()` calls)

Comment: Identifying expressions that can be safely optimized is expensive, so it's a toss-up whether it's worth doing so. In your example, it cannot be safely done, unless you analyze your entire program to ensure that `pp` (or `map`, for that matter) is never bound to a different value.

Comment: Regarding whole-program analysis, few languages do this. Python modules are compiled independently of any other module that might be included in your code, which is why every module has its own global namespace. Further, modules aren't immutable: you might have `X = 5` in your module and ensure that the value is never changed in the module, but code importing your module can modify the value: `import some_module; some_module.X = 7`.

Comment: that's almost exactly what's done by the julia programming language, python on the other hand has to make a lot of performance compromises to allow the language to be as dynamic as possible, as noted in the answer, most of python code cannot be predicted before it actually executes, just imagine you are simply adding two numbers, the function that will be called at runtime to do this sum can change at runtime, also in your example `pp` can change before or while the function is executing (from another thread) so it's impossible to predict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always a cost to identify expressions that *can* safely be reduced in a dynamic language like Python. For instance,

```
X = 5

def fun():
    return X * 5
```

cannot be optimized to

```
def fun():
    return 25
```

without whole-program analysis that verifies that `X` is never assigned a different value. Python itself does not specify any such optimizations, but individual implementations are free to add optimizations as they see fit. For example, CPython will optimize certain constant expressions and eliminate dead code under some conditions. You can see this using the `dis` module to see the byte code generated for a given function.

```
>>> def fun(): return 5*5
...
>>> dis.dis(fun)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (25)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

or

```
>>> def fun():
...     if False:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return 5
...
>>> dis.dis(fun)
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

The conditional expression is not similarly optimized.

```
>>> def fun():
...     return 1 if False else 5
...
>>> dis.dis(fun)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (False)
              2 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        8
              4 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
        >>    8 LOAD_CONST               3 (5)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

I suspect this is because the optimizer doesn't want to dive into *expressions* to identify dead code, only statements (which exist at a higher level in the AST). You can stop the optimization by replacing `False` with an expression that could be evaluated to `False` at compile time, but the optimizer similarly does not.

```
>>> def fun():
...     if 3 == 5:
...         return 1
...     else: return 5
...
>>> dis.dis(fun)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12

  3           8 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

  4     >>   12 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

OK, automatically identifying code that is safe to simplify is hard; maybe there could be a way to mark code to be simplified. But even such syntax would *still* need to verify the optimization is safe. Consider the first example above; you could *say* that it's safe to optimize `X * 5`, but what is Python supposed to do about the following?

```
X = 5

def fun():
    return __precompute__(X * 5)

X = 7
```

If you precompute `fun`, it will always return `25`, even though you changed the value of `X` before `fun` is ever called. This just makes the definition of `fun` confusing, and you could have just written `return 25` in the first place if that was your intent. Remember, the code generator is constrained by what *could* be done, not what you *intend* to be done.

Given that such marked code *still* has to be analyzed for safety, is it really worth complicating the grammar for something that isn't really any more useful than automatic optimization?

Comment: I responded to your post in the update to my question. Read it, please

Comment: That's another case where yes, the compiler *could* take the current values of `parent_1` et al. into account when defining the function, but again: each variable is an *expression* that the code generator would have to look at, much like `3 == 5` in my answer above, not a hard-coded keyword like `False` that the parser can recognize. *Could* the compiler optimize this? Sure. *Does* it? No, at least not at this time.

Comment: It doesn't, but can, why not? It seems to me that we are missing a language with the flexibility of Python and C++ optimizations.  And more strict typing than in Python.  In any case, thanks for the replies.

Comment: The cost to identify optimizable code has to be paid by *everyone*, whether their code will benefit from the search or not. (The optimization itself is not the expensive part; it's combing through all possible expressions that *maybe*, but usually *won't*, have any optimizable code.) If the expected return isn't high enough, there's no justification to slow down compilation for the users who won't benefit. That burden is shifted to the coder to optimize their own code.

Comment: Part of this is just cultural. Python has long been used for rapid prototyping, because of the rapid turnaround between making changes to code and being able to run it and see the effect. There is a higher bar for anything that might increase compilation time to be addd to the language. (For a very long time, changes to the grammar could not violate the invariant that the grammar could be parsed by an LL(1) parser, to avoid increasing the cost of parsing Python code.)

Comment: (As one example, IIRC, the conditional expression `T if C else F` was chosen over `if C then T else F` partly because the latter could not be distinguished from an `if` statement by an LL(1) parser.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should think about the problem from another point of view,

Yes expressions with only constants are evaluated by the interpreter and might not be optimized by it, but why care about this?

If a function given a number of arguments `foo(x0, x1, x3, x4, ...) = C` always returns the same value is cachable hence it will be evaluated only once

```
>>> from math import factorial as fact
>>> from functools import lru_cache
>>> import time
>>> 
>>> @lru_cache
... def foo(n):
...     return fact(n)
... 
>>> def timefoo(foo, args):
...     start = time.time()
...     foo(*args)
...     return time.time()-start
>>> timefoo(foo, (998,))
6.508827209472656e-05
>>> timefoo(foo, (998,))
2.1457672119140625e-06
```